# How to concatenate address members in C# while dealing with nulls and commas

Tags: c#

I am trying to concatenate address lines eloquently, delimited by commas, but where a line is null, to omit the comma.

My current proposal is :

```
    public string fullAddress
    {
        get
        {
            return $"{address.line1 ?? ""}, {address.line2 ?? ""}, {address.line3 ?? "" } , {address.line4 ?? ""}"; 
        }

    }
```

But the above does not deal with the null commas. What would be a more eloquent way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks, I am using MVC5, .Net 4.7 so I am using C# 7.3 ..... apologies... I have deleted the C# 3 tag. It does work in C# 7.3 and produces "A1, A2, A3 , A4"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd put the items into an array, filter the nulls out then join them.

```
return string.Join(", ", new[]{address.line1, address.line2, address.line3, address.line4}.Where(s => s != null));
```

or as suggested in the comments by @Avin Kavish:

```
return string.Join(", ", new[]{address.line1, address.line2, address.line3, address.line4}.Where(s => !string.isNullOrWhiteSpace(s)));
```